# catching std::exception by reference?

Tags: c++

I have a silly question. I read this article about std::exception http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

On `catch (exception& e)`, it says:

> We have placed a handler that catches exception objects by reference (notice the ampersand & after the type), therefore this catches also classes derived from exception, like our myex object of class myexception.

Does this mean that by using "&" you can also catch exception of the parent class? I thought & is predefined in std::exception because it's better to pass e (std::exception) as reference than object.

Comment: I don't understand your last paragraph. Passing by reference has nothing to do with exceptions and is fundamental in C++ to allow for runtime polymorphism.

Comment: The answer is no - the objects you can catch must be derived from the exception type you are catching, as you mentioned in your post. This exhibits the IS-A relationship. You can not catch a parent class if you only specify children in the catch clauses.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The reason for using `&` with exceptions is not so much polymorphism as avoiding [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). If you were to not use `&`, C++ would attempt to copy the thrown exception into a newly created `std::exception`, potentially losing information in the process. Example:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class my_exception : public std::exception {
  virtual const char *what() const throw() {
    return "Hello, world!";
  }
};

int main() {
  try {
    throw my_exception();
  } catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This will print the default message for `std::exception` (in my case, `St9exception`) rather than `Hello, world!`, because the original exception object was lost by slicing. If we change that to an `&`:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class my_exception : public std::exception {
  virtual const char *what() const throw() {
    return "Hello, world!";
  }
};

int main() {
  try {
    throw my_exception();
  } catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now we do see `Hello, world!`.

Comment: +1; Wow, your example and answer look remarkably like mine.  Are you sitting behind me? ;)

Comment: @Merlyn, nope, I think it's just the simplest way to demonstrate the problem :)

Comment: +bdonlan i don't understand that `virtual const char *what() const throw() {`   two functions? what() & throw() can you explain this syntax for function. I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @androidplusios.design It defines a virtual function named what, returning `const char *`, that can be invoked on a `const` object (the second `const`) and that never throws exceptions `throw()`. This is the proper way to override `what()` on `std::exception`

Comment: To be nitpicking: Since `what()` is defined as virtual in `std::exception`, you might want to use `const char *what() const throw() override` or better `const char *what() const throw() final`.

Answer (score 10):

> Does this mean that by using "&" you can also catch exception of the parent class?

No, this doesn't increase the scope of where you will catch exceptions from (e.g. from the parent class of the class that contains the try/catch code).

It also doesn't increase the types of exceptions that can be caught, compared to catching by value (`catch(std::exception e)` without the `&` - you'll still catch each exception that either is `std::exception` or derives from it).

What it increases is the amount of data that you will actually get when you catch the exception.

If an exception is thrown that derives from `std::exception`, and you catch it by value, then you are throwing out any extra behavior in that exception class.  It breaks [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) on the exception class, because of [Slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

An example:

```
class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const
    {
        return "hello, from my exception!";
    }
};

// ...

try
{
    throw MyException();
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    // This will print "hello, from my exception!"
    std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
}

// ...

try
{
    throw MyException();
}
catch(std::exception e)
{
    // This will print "Unknown exception"
    std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No the `&` has absolutely no bearing on the polymorphic nature of exception handlers. Their wording is very poor, it does seem to indicate that the `&` is somehow responsible. This is not the case. You are correct, `&` just passes by reference which is a tad more efficient.

Also as a general rule, <strike>[you should really try to avoid cplusplus.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/88241/22976)</strike>.

**Updated link:** [What's wrong with cplusplus.com](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com)

Comment: @sje397 hmm, it looks like they deleted the article, I've updated the link.

Comment: the new link is dead

Answer (score 0):

Using reference to exception here can reduce the temporary objects created, and it can also keep the polymorphism.