# How does C++ exception handling deal with exception derived classes?

Tags: c++, exception

If I am catching `BaseException` will this also catch exceptions which derive from `BaseException`? Does exception handling care about inheritance, etc, or does it only match the *exact* exception type being caught?

```
class MyException {
...
};
class MySpecialException : public MyException {
...
};
```

---

```
void test()
{
 try {
 ...
 }
 catch (MyException &e) {
   //will this catch MySpecialException?
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you written any code to try it out?

Comment: Nope. All my work is in an IDE so creating a 10 line tst program requires a bunch of messing about. Oh for an online GCC compiler :)

Comment: Skizz, try ideone.com :)

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov that's pretty damn awesome

Comment: my feeling is that this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755991/catching-stdexception is what you are looking for, use references to prevent slicing (answer 1 with 10 upvotes should be) - edit: since you already reference-used, you are save.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy to explain with code: http://ideone.com/5HLtZ

```
#include <iostream>

class ExceptionBase {
};

class MyException : public ExceptionBase {
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw MyException();
    }
    catch (MyException const& e) {
        std::cout<<"catch 1"<<std::endl;
    }
    catch (ExceptionBase const& e) {
        std::cout<<"should not catch 1"<<std::endl;
    }

    ////////
    try
    {
        throw MyException();
    }
    catch (ExceptionBase const& e) {
        std::cout<<"catch 2"<<std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout<<"should not catch 2"<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:
catch 1
catch 2

Answer (score 6):

C++ exception handling will match the exception subclasses.  However, it performs a linear search from the first catch() to the last, and will only match the first one.  So if you intend to catch both Base and Derived, you would need to catch(MySpecialException &) first.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will, this is very common.  It's common for example to catch `std::exception` despite the fact that the exception thrown is likely to be a derived exception like `std::bad_alloc` or `std::runtime_error`.

You can actually catch the base type and the derived and they will be caught in turn, but you must catch the derived type first.

```
try
{
   // code which throws bad_alloc
}
catch ( const std::bad_alloc & e )
{
   // handle bad_alloc
}
catch ( const std::exception & e )
{
   // catch all types of std::exception, we won't go here 
   // for a bad_alloc because that's been handled.
}
catch ( ... )
{
   // catch unexpected exceptions
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will catch exceptions derived from the base.

Answer (score 1):

## include

class ExceptionBase {
};

class MyException : public ExceptionBase {
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw MyException();
    }
    catch (MyException const& e) {
        std::cout<<"catch 1"<

```
////////
try
{
    throw MyException();
}
catch (ExceptionBase const& e) {
    std::cout<<"catch 2"<<std::endl;
}
catch (...) {
    std::cout<<"should not catch 2"<<std::endl;
}

return 0;
```